# ResponseError in opensearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, api-gateway

I have called "GET" method.
And I got ResonseError

```
{
    "errorType": "ResponseError",
    "errorMessage": "Response Error",
    "name": "ResponseError",
    "meta": {
        "body": "Unauthorized",
        "statusCode": 401,
        "headers": {
            "date": "Sat, 29 Apr 2023 08:41:44 GMT",
            "content-type": "text/plain;charset=UTF-8",
            "content-length": "12",
            "connection": "keep-alive",
            "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
            "www-authenticate": "Basic realm=\"OpenSearch Security\""
        }
```

I have tried opensearch stream on dynamodb data from postman through API Gateway.